# Ruby on Rails Partial Locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

On my site users can both take and retake a quiz, meaning I will use the quiz code in a partial view that will be used both by the the edit and new views.

To render my partials I have in my new view:

`<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: quiz_bs_path } %>`

and in my edit view:

```
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: { url: edit_quiz_b_path } %>
```

The `link_to` locations are from my rake routes results:

```
        quiz_bs GET    /quiz_bs(.:format)             quiz_bs#index
                POST   /quiz_bs(.:format)             quiz_bs#create
     new_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/new(.:format)         quiz_bs#new
    edit_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id/edit(.:format)    quiz_bs#edit
         quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#show
                PATCH  /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#update
                PUT    /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#update
                DELETE /quiz_bs/:id(.:format)         quiz_bs#destroy
```

I am getting an Argument Error in my edit view saying `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`.  The line on which the error is being called is in my partial:

`<%= form_for @quiz_bs, url: url, method: :post do |f| %>`

My controller code is:

```
class QuizBsController < ApplicationController
before_action :require_sign_in

def show
@quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @quiz_bs = current_user.quiz_bs || current_user.build_quiz_bs
end

def create
@quiz_bs = QuizBs.new

@quiz_bs.bs01 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs01]
@quiz_bs.bs02 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs02]
@quiz_bs.bs03 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs03]
@quiz_bs.bs04 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs04]
@quiz_bs.bs05 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs05]
@quiz_bs.bs06 = params[:quiz_bs][:bs06]

@quiz_bs.user = current_user

if @quiz_bs.save
  flash[:notice] = "Quiz results saved successfully."
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
else
  flash[:alert] = "Sorry, your quiz results failed to save."
  redirect_to welcome_index_path
end
end

def update
@quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:quiz_bs])

@quiz_bs.assign_attributes(quiz_bs_params)

if @quiz_bs.save
  flash[:notice] = "Post was updated successfully."
  redirect_to user_path(current_user)
else
  flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
  redirect_to welcome_index_path
end
end

private
def quiz_bs_params
  params.require(:quiz_bs).permit(:bs01, :bs02, :bs03, :bs04, :bs05, :bs06)
end

end
```

The model is:

```
class QuizBs < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_bscode

  def set_bscode
    self.bscode = "#{self.bs01}#{self.bs02}#{self.bs03}-#{self.bs04}#{self.bs05}#{self.bs06}"
  end

  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: try pass `quiz` inline, without usage of locals

Comment: Check to make sure `@quiz_bs` is proper.

Comment: Upon which action you are getting the error? new or edit? Also Please post your controller code.

Comment: So much better passing quiz inline without locals (and edited to reflect it), but it just changed the error code.  I also showed my quiz_bs controller.

Comment: Your controller doesn't have edit action. Did you missed it?

Comment: @Liz which errors code is without locals?

Comment: I did miss it!  Added in

`def edit
    @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
  end` 

which got rid of that error message, but it's displaying `Couldn't find QuizBs with 'id'=1` even though it exists...

Comment: @Liz set assignment of `@quiz_bs` as in the update action

Comment: I made the definition of edit in the controller match the update action and am still getting a 'record not found' saying `Couldn't find QuizBs with 'id'=`

Comment: @Liz I saw, in your routes what to edit/update/show action is passed `id`, so search should be by id, but, may be really you haven;'t yet cerated that quiz?

Comment: Try `QuizBs.find(1)` in rails console (in terminal, from the app folder, run `rails console`). If that does not work even though a QuizBs with id 1 exists, then there is something not working in your model

Comment: Type `raise params.inspect` in edit action and tell me what params are coming.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a record with a QuizBs with id 1.  Yet there is one record.  How do I get it to bypass id = 1 and go to the existing record?

Comment: @Liz just trial purposes you can use `QuizBs.first`, or create a new quiz before

Comment: Can you post your model code ?

Comment: Edited with the model code.

Comment: And I used the rails console to create a quiz with id = 1.  It's now pointing me to my `def quiz_bs_params` saying `param is missing or the value is empty: quiz_bs`.

Comment: @Liz see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it more simple, if you want to assign to current_user, `create` method will do for you.

**Partial:**

```
#new.html.erb
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: {quiz: @quiz_bs, url: :quiz_bs } %>


#edit.html.erb
<%= render partial: "quiz", locals: {quiz: @quiz_bs, url: :quiz_b } %>
```

**Form:**

```
#_form.html.erb

<%= form_for quiz, url: url do |f| %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def new
  @quiz_bs = QuisBs.new
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `edit` action in controller, so rails assumes it being empty. Thus `@quiz_bs` is really `nil`

Add something like

```
def edit
  @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
end
```

also in your `update` action `params[:quiz_bs]` is most likely `nil` too and should be changed to `params[:id]`

Comment: I saw conditions where empty action isn't requireed.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ not in this case, when OP needs the action to set instance variable

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to create RESTfull methods in controller but if you are using it as I can see `@quiz_bs` then you will have to initialize it first then you can use it, In your new view you initialize the `@quiz_bs` by

```
@quiz_bs = current_user.quiz_bs || current_user.build_quiz_bs
```

then you are using it.

and also `routes` which is generated for `edit` is needed an `id` i.e.

```
edit_quiz_b GET    /quiz_bs/:id/edit(.:format)    quiz_bs#edit
```

so you will have to pass `@quiz_bs` like

```
edit_quiz_b_path(@quiz_bs)
```

GOT it?

Comment: I did try changing the path as you suggest, but it still gives the same `Couldn't find QuizBs with 'id'=` error.

Comment: Did you define `edit` method on your controller ?
`def edit
  @quiz_bs = QuizBs.find(params[:id])
end`

Answer (score 0):

Some updates to your controller:

```
before_action :assign_quiz_bs, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
#...   
def update
   @quiz_bs.update(quiz_bs_params)

   # .... rendering ...
end

private

def assign_quiz_bs
   @quiz_bs = Quiz.find(params[:id])
end

def quiz_bs_params
   params.require(:quiz_bs).permit(:bs01, :bs02, :bs03, :bs04, :bs05, :bs06)
end
```